# Not able to get successful response from JMETER request

Tags: jmeter

I am new to JMETER.

Steps I am following are:
1. Login 
2. Navigation
3. Posting values in Request

I am able to do first two steps i.e. Login and Navigation successfully by posting parameters from "Send Parameters With the Request".

When I am trying to posting parameters from "Send Parameters With the Request" in third step i am getting Response like values are null

**Request from Result Tree:**

*POST https://www.test.net/Databases/Employee/Add
POST data:
MyNo=EMP004&Badge=EMP004&FirstName=EMP004&LastName=EMP004
Cookie Data:
.ASPXAUTH=7A01E1CDB1496B775ABB4D1A3E811E6DE6556141ED9F7EF3CF16FB6BE9EEC88B7446286A9249810B91C3D735BCFB6C8533FFA70E37E9161AC62D42C36CC3B2AF55B71BB261B5C77D536A3164BF024D36BED56196E84D575D333F529E56E4770C7E0BF5CFC06B4C5D04E40644B715D502; __RequestVerificationToken=2YhJX3pX3zYamRsdW_6htKtskarUoVbGZ_swGTT4AAtUMgIpYd-gfUtOQuRfUm3Il6oXE-6DhIz2AZDG5Z6R8BxI751RMw1Bj95WxGySRhs1; ASP.NET_SessionId=4nqsuzqt3jj3ey3ovvfy4waq
Request Headers:
Connection: keep-alive
Origin: https://www.test.net
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarynUCTUgtyzyFTH1Xx
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: https://www.test.net/Databases/Employee/Add
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Content-Length: 382
Host: www.test.net*

**Response:**

Employee: *
 Employee can not be empty.
First Name: *
 First Name can not be empty.
Last Name: *
 Last Name can not be empty.
Badge: *
 Badge can not be empty.

Comment: Try to send as JSON data from Body Data or upload the screenshot

Comment: This has been resolved, I was passing the wrong headers while posting the values.
Thanks!!